# Build is Stuck in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2015

I have this build Machine at a remote location. The process of building a full install is that first I update my code via SVN update and then open Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and build the solution in Release Mode, once that is done I would then open Advanced Installer to build the package to an executable.

But from Friday I am unable to build my code with visual studio 2015, it would seem that build is happening but I am not seeing Build Successful, its been an hour and I had to kill the process(devenv) to Cancel the build.

The only delta which happened from last time is that SVN in my organization is running into some issues in which writes are failing, but logically it doesn't make any sense that visual studio wouldn't build a solution because there is an issue with SVN. I mean, one can argue saying that maybe there is a read error too but I am positive that I have all the necessary code files to build the solution, and for the sake of argument if we say I hadn't, shouldn't I have run into build errors rather than a hung build?

**Note 1**: Output window is of no use, as I do not see any meaningful error.
**Note 2**: I checked the solution out in another directory but same result.
**Note 3**: Build Machine has Windows 7 Professional SP1 in it.

Any insight to this weird behavior is appreciated.

Comment: There is really not a lot to go on here, have tried to build it locally?

Comment: Yes, and that builds all the time. I am lost, is my visual studio broken?

Comment: Does any other applications build, test projects?

Comment: I am also thinking on creating a small project on build machine and giving a try to build in release to see of at least that works.

Comment: I think that would be a good start

Comment: I got another idea too, just for kicks this time I will try to build one project at a time

Comment: I am outside but will post my observations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build the solution after restarting the Build Machine. I looked into the system log to see when was the last time the computer was restarted and to my surprise, I found that it was never restarted even once. I had been using this Machine at least from 2 years.

As I wrote, restarting the PC solved the issue but I do not know the reason which helped the case here. I am guessing there were memory leaks?

Any person reading this post to solve similar issue may want to start by restarting the Build Machine.